# Filtering Eloquent ORM query by relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to filter my Eloquent query by relation. I have following relations:

`User **has many** achievements`

`Game **has many** achievements`

Now I need to filter achievements of user A to those gained in game B. This can be done this way:

`$user->achievements()->whereGameId($game->id)`

This is fine, but can I use $game object directly instead of filtering by ugly ID column?

Comment: Check my edit, working solution sent as a PR

Answer (score 0):

edit:

**So here's the PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4267 that lets you do this**:

```
// 'game' being relation on the Achievement model
$user->achievements()->hasIn('game', $game);
// or equivalent dynamic call
$user->achievements()->hasInGame($game);

// of course you may use it like any other Builder method, for example:
User::hasInAchievements($achievement)->get();
```

---

No straightforward way to do this, unless the `Game` is related somehow to the `User`.

To be clear, say `User` and `Game` is related, then you can access achievements on the games Collection injecting `Game` model instead of 'ugly' `$game->id`:

```
$user->games->find($game)->achievements;
```

Comment: Dude, user doesn't have anything to do with games.

Comment: So what is exactly that you expect? Not refering to $game->id and make it look better by injecting $game instead?

Comment: @RafałWalczak If you look at @deczo’s code more closely, you’ll notice he’s using dot notation to go from the `games` table to `achievements`. Have a look at eager loading nested relationships in the Laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: I mean something like `$user->achievements()->whereGame($game)`. I know how to do it manually, but I wonder if that can be done without any interaction with ID column to make it more flexible.

Comment: @MartinBean I see, but why would I use it? It's less elegant than the one I gave as an example, as it uses ID column directly (like mine) and is uglier.

Comment: @RafałWalczak `$user= User::with('games.achievements');` does not use the ID column, but fetches achievements associated with games that is associated with a user.

Comment: @RafałWalczak I don’t understand your reluctance in using an ID. That’s how your records are related. There’s no other way to fetch the relation. That’s like saying I want to get to America from the UK, without travelling across water.

Comment: I have to agree with OP that it's a nice and easy way for the relations. I'm just having a look at how easy or hard it's going to be implementing that.

Comment: @MartinBean This is beauty of ORM. You don't care about things that artificial as primary keys. One day I could want to name them `frog` or `cabbage` and it should be configurable in one place. Relations in ORM don't involve providing primary key name, because API doesn't care about it. That's why I asked if that can be done in beautiful way. I know some people don't care about what's elegant and what's not, they just care if it works or not.

Comment: I got my hands dirty and just made it work. After some tests tomorrow or the day after gonna send a pull request to Taylor.

Comment: @deczo How are you planning to do that? What would be the method name?

Comment: It's pretty close to `has()` method, for the name I have to think to make it verbose, but probably something like hasRelated{RelationName}.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting `$game` object into a closure method and doing querying while eager loading is a way better approach in my opinion.

`whereHas` and `orWhereHas` is for limiting the result by querying relations.

```
$game = Game::find($gameID);
//magic happens here
$users = User::whereHas('achievements', function($query) use($game){
        $query->where('gameId', $game->id);
    })
    ->with('achievments') //if you want to have them inside collection
    ->get();
```

This limits both `User` (main collection result) along with `achievments` (relation).

[Here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations)'s a detailed information (Querying Relations).

If you just want to filter `achievments`, but not `User` collection, you just need a closure function on eager loading:

```
$game = Game::find($gameID);
//magic happens here
$users = User::with(
        array('achievements' => function($query) use($game){
        $query->where('gameId', $game->id);
    }))
    ->get();
```

This just limits `achievments` relation, but does not affect `User` (main collection)

[Here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)'s a detailed description (Eager Loading Constains)

Comment: This does the same thing as my example, but is way more complicated.

Comment: @RafałWalczak if OP is in a loop, your answer does not eager load, which is a serious performance issue on big data.

Comment: Like I said: currently there is no way to inject Model into Query Builder methods to do what OP wants.